# How to set page size for a specific page

Tags: python, python-pdfkit

I am using `pdfkit` in Python to convert my Django template to PDF.

I am going to generate a pdf with 3 pages and I need my last page size should be `landscape`.

I tried with `options` parameter but couldn't find how to apply `page_size` for a specific page.

Note: Please comment if you are unclear with the question rather down voting, losing interest in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a slight misunderstanding landscape is an orientation not a page size, here i'm assuming you want your last page to be in the landscape orientation.

Having a page in the landscape orientation means that it is the same size as your previous pages just that it will be horizontally presented rather than vertically. You can change this property by setting the `layout` property of the last page to **landscape**.

Comment: I am adding options `options = { 'page-size': 'Letter', 'no-outline': None`}` but the `page_size` is applied on all pages. I just want apply `page_size` on only 3rd page of pdf.